# Rollup summary field always "currently being calculated" in spring '13 orgs

Tags: roll-up-summary

We are having an issue in an sandbox updated to Spring '13. After saving a record that has rollup summary fields, several summary fields (4 out of 6) will have an hourglass icon next to them with a note "This field is currently being calculated. Please check again later." This icon never goes away. The object and fields are in our managed package.

We have seen the issue in a customer org and reproduced it in our own Spring '13 sandbox. In a Winter '13 sandbox with, as far as I can tell, everything else the same, the rollup fields all work fine.

Has anyone seen anything like this before? Anything we can try while we wait for salesforce support to respond?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, there is a similar known issue, see

After Spring '13 release, Roll-up Summary Fields that are part of managed packages show "recalculating" icon after patch upgrade

http://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000StzWAAS

You can check the fix status there.

Comment: Thanks. That's my issue from working with salesforce support for almost a week. I forgot to come back here and update.